# How to identify which versions of python libraries are used in exe created through pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows-installer, pyinstaller, python-import, exe

I have an exe file build through pyinstaller. Along with the exe file, I have a few dlls and pyd files too. These pyd files are of the libraries being used, like pandas, numpy, etc.,

How do I identify which version of pandas/numpy was bundled during build for creating exe?

**Note:** I do not have the command which was used to build this. I have just been told that it was done using pyinstaller. Nor do I have the machine where this code was built. There are no requirements.txt files in place as well. I have just been told to identify the versions of libraries the app is using. Is there any way I can identify that?

Answer (score 1):

You can decompile an exe built using pyinstaller by extracting the pyc's using something like pyinstxtractor and than you can use a Python decompiler on those to get the py files. In the process of running pyinstxtractor you will be told the version of python that was used if your version differs. The benefit of this method is that you will also see all of the libraries that were used in the exe.

---

Download:
[pyinstxtractor](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor/tree/master)

Install uncompyle: `pip install uncompyle6`

---

Now you can run...

`pyinstxtractor.py <file.exe>`

This will output the dll's, pyc, and other files associated with the exe.

If you want to read the pyc files you can run [uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) on them to convert them to readable .py files.